# Showing that $(Ax)(t) = x'(t)$ is a Fredholm operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Can you help me to prove that the operator $A \colon C^1[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$,
$$(Ax)(t) = x'(t)$$
is a Fredholm operator and find $\alpha(A) = \dim(\operatorname{Ker} A)$ and $\beta(A) = \operatorname{codim} (\operatorname{Im} A)$?

I have no idea.

Comment: What is the topology on these spaces? Do you know the definition of a Fredholm operator?

Comment: Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator for definitions. Try to start at the begging making sure you understand what Banach spaces are and which 2 are involved here.

Comment: I guess you are considering the uniform topology on $C[0,1])$ and the topology on $C^1[0,1]$ generated by the nom $f\mapsto \|f\|_u+\|f'\|_u$. Just for the kernel of $A$, notice that it consists of constant fuctions only. So $dim Ker_A=1$.

Comment: Using the fundamental of calculus, it seems to me that $\operatorname{Im}(A)=C[0,1]$. If so, the codimentsion of $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear operator $A$ is [Fredholm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator), by definition, if an only if both $\ker A$ and $\text{coker} A$ are of finite dimension, and the range of $A$ is closed.

I assume both $C([0, 1])$ and $C^1([0, 1])$ are understood in the usual sense, that is, as the spaces of continuous and once-continuously differentiable complex-valued functions on $[0, 1]$, respectively with the usual norms; that is, for

$f(x) \in C([0,1]) \tag 1$

we have

$\Vert f(x) \Vert_0 = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \vert f(x) \vert, \tag 2$

whilst for

$f(x) \in C^1([0,1]), \tag 3$

$\Vert f(x) \Vert_1 = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} (\vert f(x) \vert + \vert f'(x) \vert); \tag 4$

it is then clear that the operator

$A:C^1([0, 1]) \to C([0, 1]), \; A(f(x)) = f'(x) \tag 5$

is bounded, since

$\Vert A(f(x)) \Vert_0 = \Vert f'(x) \Vert_0 = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]}\vert f'(x) \vert$
$\le \sup_{x \in [0, 1]}(\vert f(x) \vert + \vert f'(x) \vert) = \Vert f(x) \Vert_1 \tag 6$

which shows that

$\Vert A \Vert \le 1. \tag7$

Now if

$A(f(x)) = f'(x) = 0, \tag 8$

then

$f(x) = c,\; \text{a constant}, \tag 9$

and since the derivative of a constant function vanishes, it follows that

$\ker A = \{c, \; c \in \Bbb C \}, \tag{10}$

so clearly,

$\alpha(A) = \dim \ker A = 1. \tag{11}$

Now if

$g(x) \in C([0, 1]), \tag{12}$

we may define

$f(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x g(s) \; ds \in C^1([0, 1]); \tag{13}$

then clearly

$A(f(x)) = f'(x) = g(x); \tag{13}$

thus $A$ is surjective:

$\text{Range}(A) = C([0, 1]), \tag{14}$

from which we see that

$\text{coker}(A) = C([0, 1]) / \text{Range}(A) = C([0, 1]) / C([0, 1]) = \{0\}, \tag{15}$

whence

$\beta(A) = \dim \text{coker}(A) = 0. \tag{16}$

By (14), $\text{Range}(A)$ is evidently closed.

We have thus verified that $A$ is indeed a Fredholm operator.